# web service data transfer question

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

Applicatins are built by using C#. one of the tasks is transfer a image file from server to client via web service (SOAP). in the client side, the image file will be saved to disk, no web page.

one of my co-workers told us, the data transferred between server and client must be under 8k, so we need to cut our image file, which is 2M, into smaller pieces.

is that true?

Right now the data can be transferred between client and server. The size is right but the content is not because the display is not the same when we open the received file. My co-workers tried different encoding but none works.

which encoding we should use? UTF8?

Comment: "one of my co-workers told us, the data transferred between server and client must be under 8k" because?

Comment: Why is this question not posed towards your coworker that said this? Why are you accepting his advice at face-value when it is plain obvious you do not trust him? Why not ask him to back up his claim with facts that can be checked? And just for the record, **no**, it is not true.

Comment: he is expert on that field and I have limited experience on that area. I asked him why there is that limitation. He told us it is standard. I think he is using WCF and SOAP to create this parts of our application.

Comment: Any "expert" will be able to back up their claims with facts and examples.  Also, any "standard" will have documentation backing it up.  Sounds like they really aren't an expert as the advise is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could to open that image file as a byte[] and to transfer it. This way you shouldn't have any encoding problem. This article can provide more information: [Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can change default limit for WCF request/response message size by setting `MaxReceivedMessageSize` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxreceivedmessagesize.aspx) in configuration.
And it's reasonable to transfer image as a binary object, not string.

You will probably also have to adjust other limit settings, like max array size, max string size, etc.